# Is Trillian application unsafe? (Got "Someone has your password" message from Google)

Tags: passwords, android, google, account-security

Trying to connect to GoogleTalk from the Trillian app for Android (a universal instant messenger app), I got denied even with the correct password. Then Google e-mailed me saying that my password is compromised and that an access to my account was blocked from IP `74.201.35.40` (somewhere in the USA).

Does it mean the Trillian application is spoiled (trying to steal my Google account), or is it just poorly programmed so that it's their server that connects to Google rather than me? Or something else? Should I stop using the app?

Comment: Well in that case I probably shouldn't poke fun. Usually you wouldn't say an IT product has become spoiled, rather a food, or situation. Regardless, doing a `whois` on that IP shows it is owned by Cerulean Studios, the people who make Trillian. Was it the first time you tried using Trillian? Sounds like Trillian might not be a Google Trusted app. To check you can go in your google setting and check allow unverified apps and see if it works.

Comment: @cremefraiche You can, I just need some hint that it's a joke, otherwise I'm confused....

Comment: Yo, I think @cremefraiche was surprised at your choice of the word 'spoiled'. While not wrong, it is not a word that a native speaker would choose. Perhaps 'broken' or 'faulty' are more appropriate.

Comment: @NeilSmithline well, I should have said "unsafe" probably then.

Comment: Much better. At the end of his comment, Creme suggested you tweak your Google settings.

Answer (score 2):

Your case is documented in the [Trillian Security Practices](https://www.trillian.im/policies/security/). The mobile device version of the software will store your Google password **encrypted** on the company servers of the Trillian developers. This allows them to keep your GoogleTalk session alive, even if your mobile device has bad connectivity. It also allows you to use the web version of the Trillian application.

If you reset your Trillian password, then all your stored third-party credentials are lost, since they are encrypted with the lost password. This underlines their claim that third-party passwords are stored encrypted.

Given this setup, it is really the case that the Trillian company server connects to Google with your decrypted clear-text password. Google detects the company server as origin and blocks it if your other devices are far away from the U.S. (see comment by @cremefraiche).

To make GTalk work in Trillian on mobile devices, go to your [Google Security Dashboard](https://security.google.com/settings/security/notifications) and mark the server as trustworthy for Google logins.

If you don't like this approach at all, stop using Trillian in the mobile and web version. Delete your Trillian account and change all passwords you ever entered into their application.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for using an app password, as well, so you can simply revoke access to that password instead of changing your main account password if you stop using Trillian.